# writeToURL: error handling

Tags: cocoa, file-io, error-handling, nsdata, nserror

The file handling in Cocoa is quite simple, several of the classes handle messages as the following (e.g. NSData)

```
writeToURL:options:error:
```

But the documentation of the error statement is quite useless. Just "NSError object that describes the problem"

Ok but where are all the possible errors documented? 
Did I miss the relevant link? I expect the list is not endless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have noticed that an instance of `NSError` includes a property called `domain`. This is a string, three of which are defined: `NSPOSIXErrorDomain`, `NSOSStatusErrorDomain`, and `NSMachErrorDomain`. Each domain has error codes unique to it, or at least have special meaning in their contexts.

For `NSPOSIXErrorDomain`, look in `sys/errno.h`.

Likewise, for `NSOSStatusErrorDomain`, look in `CarbonCore/MacErrors.h`.

For `NSMachErrorDomain`, look in `mach/error.h`.

Frameworks can define their own domains, and an example of this is `NSCocoaErrorDomain`, for which you should look in `Foundation/FoundationErrors.h`.

Keep in mind that you can define your own error domains and codes you in your own projects.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.

Comment: Thx for the hint, i think i found it. If you add the domain NSCocoaErrorDomain and the header file Foundation/FoundationErrors.h I will accept your answer.